# Inserting a pdf file into Exam class

Tags: graphics

I'm writing a quiz using the Exam class, and I want to insert a pdf of a vector field.  The file is called 'vfield1' and it's located in the same directory as my tex file.  I'm using WinEdt 8.1 and compiling with the 'PDFTexify' button.

However, I keep getting the error message, "Package pdftex.def Error: File 'vfield1.pdf' not found." Here's the code that I have:

```
\documentclass[addpoints, 12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pagestyle{headandfoot}

\firstpageheader{Name:}{Quiz 8}{Tues 7-Mar-2017}
\extrafootheight{-3in}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\vspace{0.2in}
\fbox{
\parbox{6in}
{\centering
    To receive full and partial credit, ALL work must be shown. }}
\end{center}

\begin{questions}
\question 
Determine and justify which differential equation matches the following direction field: 
\includegraphics{vfield1.pdf}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

What's interesting is that if I use the Article class, I don't get any errors and it compiles fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics{vfield1.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Any ideas what's causing the problem in the Exam class code?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It works for me, using another image of course.  Try updating your packages, or perhaps \includegraphics{vfield1}

Comment: did you see the `{pdfpages}` package as described in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739159/inserting-a-pdf-file-in-latex ?

Comment: The`pdfpages` package doesn't work for me, but `includegraphics` does (for the first page).